# Lazarus Pascal - How to REMOVE buttons at run-time

Tags: memory-management, lazarus, freepascal, destroy

I'm dynamically creating command buttons on the form like this:

```
procedure TForm1.cmdAddClick(Sender: TObject);

var   MenuButton : TButton;

begin   MenuButton := TButton.Create(self);

ButtonCount:=ButtonCount + 1;
```

With MenuButton do

```
 begin
   Top:= 10 + Height * ButtonCount;

   Left := 10; 
   Parent := Panel1; //Parent container for the buttons.
   OnClick := @YouClicked;
   Caption := 'Menu item ' + IntToStr(ButtonCount);

 end;

end;
```

After a few times of running the above lines, I have a number of buttons.

But How do I REMOVE a specific button?

I've tried

```
FreeAndNil (TButton(Sender));
```

But it doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TestButton:=TButton.Create(Panel1);
  TestButton.SetBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
  TestButton.OnClick:=@TestButtonClick;
  TestButton.Parent:=Panel1;
end;

procedure TForm1.TestButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(TestButton);  // Crash!
end;

procedure TForm1.AnotherButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(TestButton);  // Works...
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm new to Lazarus. Could you please explain the purpose of SetBounds? Thanks!

Comment: SetBounds is just an efficient way of setting a control's properties Left, Top, Width and Height at once.

Answer (score 3):

The button must also be removed from the hierarchy. IIRC that is done by TForm.RemoveComponent?

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. Can you show me HOW the SPECIFIC button can be removed from the hierarchy? Thanks!

Comment: I tried this: **Panel1.RemoveControl(TButton(Sender));** and it seems to remove the button off the form. But I'm not sure if it frees memory... BTW, RemoveComponent does nothing. Thanks anyway for your directions.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a problem with destroying the button from inside the YouClicked event (using Sender).

If I keep object-pointers to the buttons this works outside of YouClicked:

```
TheMenuButton.Free;
```

The destructor of the button (the control) handles the cleanup in the parent.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying. I DO know that something is wrong but I don't know what... Looking at at Marco van de Voort's answer and my comment to it, do you think it does the job? as far as I know the buttons are gone. But not sure if they're taking up resources.

Comment: I don't think RemoveControl will actually destroy the button-object. In all the above examples "Sender" is used as a reference to the button so I assume we are inside the YouClicked-event. This is the only place you can NOT destroy the button (you can not destroy a button which has an active event?). If you from anywhere else (try another button's click-event) run .Free on a button it will be destroyed and it's parent's control-list will be updated.